# Connection between Grid Column and Column Definition WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

First of all, I am new to WPF and I am trying to find the proper approach to dynamically resize Column Definitions of a Grid

```
  <Grid x:Name="uxFootbarGrid" Height="40" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="8*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="105*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid x:Name="uxOrderStatusGrid" Margin="0" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftMargin, RightMargin, TopMargin, BottomMargin">
                        <TextBox Margin="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Status: CMP" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Background="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Foreground="White" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Margin="0" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftMargin, RightMargin, TopMargin, BottomMargin">
                        <TextBox x:Name="uxProcessingTextBox" Margin="0" Grid.Column="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Processing: D" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="White" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="0" TextChanged="uxProcessingTextBox_TextChanged"/>
                    </Grid>

                </Grid>
```

I have Grids inside of Grid. I am trying programatically to find the connection between those.

The idea is:

```
foreach(column in masterGrid)
{
   getAllTextBoxes()
   getTotalWidth()
   setWidthToColumnDefinitionOfMasterGrid()
}
```

All good at the moment, but I cannot find relation between Control and the Column Definition they belong to.

Comment: Do you mean finding out which column the child Grid is in and accessing that column in the ColumnDefinitions?

Comment: I have done something similar by binding a value to the column width using mvvm principals.  So my view model has a property that gets bound to the column width.

Comment: You can use [Grid.GetColumn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190633(v=vs.95).aspx) to get index of a column that your control belong to. Then you can find that column definition in a grid

Comment: I guess the first question would be why?  Is it for padding or another reason?  Generally the columns fit the content as needed by setting the modifier of to 'Auto' instead of '#*'.  If you are having to set things explicitly if memory serves WPF generally has most of those set to read only.  If you are trying to make it look different at different sizes I would look into a 'ViewBox' and wrapping an object in that.  WPF Generally is built around fitting content automatically in the presentation layer of XAML automatically.

Comment: Yes @MattL. thats what i am looking for!

Comment: @djangojazz would you please recommend a tutorial or an example to that ?

Comment: Well there are lots of good tutorials but I would recommend if you are brand new to WPF to go to Lynda.com or PluralSite.com and do getting started course.  If you want a little more this site is ancient but has good concepts on a lot of WPF and has not changed at it's core in eight years: https://www.wpftutorial.net/XAML2009.html.  If you want a really detailed understanding I would get this book: http://www.apress.com/us/book/9781430243656.  Essentially like learning any coding the more you learn the more questions you may get.

Answer (score 0):

In order to find out which column an element is in, use the `Grid` class:

```
int columnIndex = Grid.GetColumn(elementName);
```

In order to access the respective column, access the collection of column definitions on the grid:

```
ColumnDefinition myColumn = uxFootbargrid.ColumnDefinitions[columnIndex];
```

Once you have the ColumnDefinition, you can go ahead and change the properties you want